# How to auto populate Laravel Nova Action Fields with their respective values from database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

This is the code I have inside my Action Class:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        Date::make('checkin_date'),
        Date::make('checkout_date'),
        Textarea::make('remark'),
        Text::make('holder_name'),
        Text::make('holder_surname'),
        Text::make('clientReference'),
    ];
}
```

[image: .]

What I'm looking for is to show the actual database value on each field. So a user would either choose to edit or keep values as they are.

Comment: Wonder how to do that too

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request object on the action definition and use a constructor to pass the value to the action.

```
class MyDemoAction extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    public function __construct(MyDemoModel $model) {
         $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        //
    }

    public function fields()
    {
    return [
        Date::make('checkin_date')->default(function() {
            $this->model->my_value;
        }),
        Date::make('checkout_date'),
        Textarea::make('remark'),
        Text::make('holder_name'),
        Text::make('holder_surname'),
        Text::make('clientReference'),
    ];
    }
```

To make sure that you can always pass a valid MyModel object, you can limit your action to only be visible on resourceDetail.
[Registering Actions](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/registering-actions.html#action-visibility)

Comment: When Nova generates the index view, the action is not passed a model in the constructor, so this method will fail in Nova 3. Not sure if Actions changed in Nova 4.

Comment: That is why I said the action can be limited to only be displayed on resource detail.